# Adding a list to a dataframe joins 1 row out

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

**PROBLEM**

I'm working on a Pandas function and have found when my list ATR_l is added to my dataframe its 1 row later than I would like.

Specifically in the Output column ATR, the result 0.457500 should be at index row 13 rather than 14 and so forth.

Other than that the calculations are giving correct results!

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

At first I though it might be an index issue between my dataframe and ATR_l list however  `print(i, ATR_l)` shows the correct ATR_l value at i(13)

I also noticed the ATR_l first value in the ATR_l list zero which i did not expect. From what I can tell this is generated when I `define` ATR_l at `ATR_l = [0]` and causing the lagging row on the ATL_l output.

When I define an empty list `ATR_l = []` i get an error thrown at `df['ATR'] = ATR_l` with `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

What are my options to remove or not add this zero to the list in the first place?

FYI - using Python 3.6

**CODE**

```
def ATRpd():                
    data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=",", header=0)
    df = data

    n = 14
    i = 0  
    TR_l = [0]  
    ATR_l = [0]

    while i < df.index[-1]:
        TR = max(df.at[i + 1, 'High'], df.at[i, 'Close']) - min(df.at[i + 1, 'Low'], df.at[i, 'Close']) 
        TR_l.append(round(TR,3))  
        i = i + 1 
    df['TR'] = TR_l
    df['MA'] = round(df.TR.rolling(n).mean(),4)

    i = 0  
    while i < df.index[-1]:        
        if i <= n - 1:
            ATR = df.at[i, 'MA']
        elif i > n - 1:               
            ATR = (ATR * 13 + df.at[i, 'TR']) / 14        
        ATR_l.append(round(ATR,6))

        if i < 20:
      #      print(i, ATR)
            print(i, ATR_l)                
        i = i + 1

    df['ATR'] = ATR_l

    print(df.head(20))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   ASXCode   DateValue   Open    High    ...     Close     TR      MA       ATR
0      BHP  26/09/2016  21.47  21.670    ...     21.55  0.000     NaN  0.000000
1      BHP  27/09/2016  21.35  21.520    ...     21.50  0.380     NaN       NaN
2      BHP  28/09/2016  21.21  21.460    ...     21.39  0.295     NaN       NaN
3      BHP  29/09/2016  22.22  22.540    ...     22.40  1.150     NaN       NaN
4      BHP  30/09/2016  22.45  22.550    ...     22.38  0.440     NaN       NaN
5      BHP   3/10/2016  22.61  22.870    ...     22.75  0.490     NaN       NaN
6      BHP   4/10/2016  22.75  22.900    ...     22.90  0.200     NaN       NaN
7      BHP   5/10/2016  22.74  22.950    ...     22.85  0.280     NaN       NaN
8      BHP   6/10/2016  23.15  23.260    ...     23.12  0.410     NaN       NaN
9      BHP   7/10/2016  23.20  23.400    ...     23.30  0.400     NaN       NaN
10     BHP  10/10/2016  23.40  23.630    ...     23.40  0.330     NaN       NaN
11     BHP  11/10/2016  23.73  23.870    ...     23.80  0.470     NaN       NaN
12     BHP  12/10/2016  23.18  23.440    ...     23.44  0.790     NaN       NaN
13     BHP  13/10/2016  23.11  23.220    ...     22.75  0.770  0.4575       NaN
14     BHP  14/10/2016  22.34  22.590    ...     22.54  0.460  0.4904  0.457500
15     BHP  17/10/2016  22.35  22.620    ...     22.39  0.330  0.4868  0.457679
16     BHP  18/10/2016  22.30  22.660    ...     22.64  0.420  0.4957  0.448559
17     BHP  19/10/2016  22.50  22.530    ...     22.47  0.600  0.4564  0.446519
18     BHP  20/10/2016  22.58  23.025    ...     22.85  0.555  0.4646  0.457482
19     BHP  21/10/2016  22.96  23.260    ...     23.04  0.410  0.4589  0.464447
```

**Output of ATR_l**

```
0 [0, nan]
1 [0, nan, nan]
2 [0, nan, nan, nan]
3 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan]
4 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
5 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
6 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
7 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
8 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
9 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
10 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
11 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
12 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
13 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.4575]
14 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.4575, 0.457679]
15 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.4575, 0.457679, 0.448559]
16 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.4575, 0.457679, 0.448559, 0.446519]
17 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.4575, 0.457679, 0.448559, 0.446519, 0.457482]
18 [0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.4575, 0.457679, 0.448559, 0.446519, 0.457482,
```

**SOLUTION 1**

Based on the great tips from `YPadawan` below I worked out I could get my original code issue fixed with adding a `+1` to `df.index[-1]+1:` of the ATR calc.

```
i = 0  
    while i < df.index[-1]+1:        
        if i <= n - 1:
            ATR = df.at[i, 'MA']
        elif i > n - 1:               
            ATR = (ATR * 13 + df.at[i, 'TR']) / 14        
        ATR_l.append(round(ATR,6))
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Taking on the advise of avoiding iterating and it necessary using `iterrows()` if is a must I landed on the following working solution which I much more succinct and easier for me to understand.

The only thing I'm contemplating is whether I can avoid the ATR iteration.

I believe I don't have a choice as i need to reference the previous row of ATR to calculate the next ATR value. Am i correct with my view on this?

```
def ATRpd2():         
    data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=",", header=0)
    df = data

    n = 14

    df['Close_prev'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
    df['TR'] = df[['High', 'Close_prev']].max(axis=1) - df[['Low', 'Close_prev']].min(axis=1)         
    df['MA'] = round(df.TR.rolling(n).mean(),6)

    ATR_l = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if idx <= n - 1:
            ATR = row['MA']          
        else:  
            ATR = (ATR * (n - 1) + row['TR']) / n        
        ATR_l.append(round(ATR,6))      
    df['ATR'] = ATR_l

    print(df.head(20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I guess this will help you. I think the ValueError you have comes from the while loop.

'while i < df.index[-1]:' will stop before it reaches df.index[-1] since you're using a strict inferiority. if the length of your data frame is 10, than i will stop at 9. Hence the resulting length will be 9 and not 10, and in pandas adding a column with a length that is different from the number of rows of the df raises `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`.

Try running this little code to understand why your while loop didn't work as you expected:

```
l = list(range(11))
print(len(l))
i = 0
l2 = []
while i < l[-1]:
    l2.append(l[i])
    i+=1
print(len(l), len(l2))
```

You should see that len(l) is greater than len(l2)...

Now actually I think it would be preferable for you to use pandas tools instead of regular loops.

Starting from your dataframe, if you want to obtain the variable TR, you should first create a columns corresponding to "i+1" values of "High" and "Low". You can  use pandas [shift method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

```
df['High_plus_one'] = df['High'].shift(1)
df['Low_plus_one'] = df['Low'].shift(1)
```

To create 'TR' column:

```
df['TR'] = df[['High_plus_one', 'Close', 'Low_plus_one']].max(axis=1)
```

For the last part if you want to create the 'ATR' columns, and you really need to iterate over your dataframe's rows. You can use the [df.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method.

```
ATR_l = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx <= n - 1:
        ATR = row['MA']
    elif idx > n - 1:               
        ATR = (ATR * 13 + row['TR']) / 14        
    ATR_l.append(round(ATR,6))
```

At the end you either avoid iterating over pandas dataframes, or you use the iterrows (or iteritems) method if you really need to.

Comment: Hi YPadawan - your tips worked out great and I  learnt a lot implementing. I will update my post with final solutions.

Comment: Based on your notes, I have been reworking my dataframe functions to avoid iterating. In the situation of the ATR formula above, I believe I don't have a choice as i need to reference the previous row of ATR to calculate the next ATR value. Am i correct with my view on this?

Comment: Hey @bassmann Your solutions look fine to me. I'm glad I could help. Indeed in the case of ATR values I don't think you can avoid iterating. Sometimes there is no other solution. Did you get the all the results you needed ?